Is there a biblical or rabbinical prohibition to commit mortgage fraud?
To simplify the question, assume a situation where the lender is a Jew.
If mortgage fraud doesn't fall under the rules of Geneiva, is it possible it's Oshek?
And in the case of a non-Jewish lender, does the rule of Hafka'at Halva'ah apply here?

What is "mortgage fraud"

@DoubleAA - here is an English law answer from https://www.stpaulschambers.com/legal-expertise/financial-and-corporate-crime/mortgage-fraud/  Mortgage fraud is a serious type of fraud and a criminal act. Put simply, mortgage fraud refers to any situation where an individual or group of individuals (say an organised crime group) misleads and defrauds a mortgage lender. This includes, but is not limited to, providing false information about: your income; your debt history; your employment; or the value of your property.

@J G please clarify what you mean by the terms Geneiva and Oshek.

@J G, is the person going to eventually pay back the loan?

A) Please clarify what the specific nature of the fraud being contemplated in the question is B) Please translate technical terms for the benefit of all (Geneiva, Oshek, Hafka'at Halva'ah): https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1607/2394

@AvishaiTebeka yes

At the very least it would be prohibited under dina demalchusa dina

Regarding the First Question:
We can argue that there is a problem of gneivat da'at (deception) because the person is deceiving the bank into giving him a loan he doesn’t deserve or has no right to. There is a machloket if it's deoritah or derabbanan. The Gemera in Chullin 94a says, דאמר שמואל אסור לגנוב דעת הבריות ואפילו דעתו של עובד כוכבים, Shmuel said: It is prohibited to deceive people, and even to deceive a gentile (look at Chullin 94a for examples of gneivat da'at). The Ritva there says that Tosfoat holds gneivat da'at is an issur deoritah, also the Smag (ל"ת קנ"ה), the Yereim (מצוה קכ"ד), and Kriat Sefer פרק י"ח ממכירה, all hold that it's an issur deoritah. However the Smak (מצוה רס"ב), Bach in Choshen Mishpat (סי' רכ"ח), and Shulchan Aruch Harav (הלכות אונאה וגניבת דעת  סעיף י"ב) all hold its derabbanan.
This would not be לא תעשוק since in Shulchan Aruch Choshen Mishpat Siman 359:8 he writes that the prohibition of oshek refers to when somebody gives you money willingly, and when it is time to give it back, you refuse to, which is not the case by mortgage fraud because here your willing to give back the money and the person doesn't willing you give the money in a retroactive sense.
Regarding the second question: הפקעת הלוואה is a complex sugya so I'll do my best:
הפקעת הלואה is where the lender who could be a non-jew lends money to a Jew and the money has reached the Jew's hand in a permissible way. The Halacha is that as long as the non-jew forgets about the loan, the Jew doesn't need to pay it back. This halacha is brought down in the Rema C.M 348:2, where the Rema quotes in the name of the Tur (and basically a lot of Rishonim and Achronim who say it's allowed). However in this case, by mortgage fraud, the Jew taking the money, takes the money b'issur (in a prohibited fashion as explained above), and because of this, we cannot apply the הפקעת הלוואה here.
Hope this makes sense!
Sources used:

https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Being_Careful_With_Other_People%27s_Money#cite_ref-47

https://minchasasher.com/he/shiur/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%AA-2/


